# Prove that a function is monotically increasing.

Tags: calculus, math-software

can someone give me a hint on how to prove 
f(x)=(3x+1)/(4-x^2) , for all x, except x=-2 and x=2
that is monotically increasing?
i know the definitions but i cannot prove it for some reason.

Comment: What does the derivative of a monotonic function show you?

Comment: i know that if  f'(x)>0 or =0 then it is monotically increasing.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: $$\frac{3x^2+2x+12}{(4-x^2)^2}>0\underbrace{\Longleftrightarrow}_{x\neq\pm2}\frac{35}{3}+3(\frac{1}{3}+x)^2>0$$

Comment: excuse me, but how did you come up with 35/3 +3(1/3 +x)^2 ?

Comment: Completing the square in the numerator.

Comment: @Kl11 $\frac{35}{3}+3(\frac{1}{3}+x)^2=\frac{35}{3}+3(\frac{(3x+1)^2}{3^2})=\frac{35}{3}+\frac{1}{3}(9x^2+6x+1)=\frac{9x^2+6x+36}{3}=3x^2+2x+12$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  given $f(x)=\dfrac{3x+1}{4-x^2}$, we have $$f'(x)=\frac{3(4-x^2)+2x(3x+1)}{(4-x^2)^2}=\frac{3x^2+2x+12}{(4-x^2)^2}.$$

How can we show that we have $f'(x)>0\ \forall x\in\Bbb R, x\neq\pm2$?